# Is cakephp suitable for enterprise application?

Tags: php, cakephp

After so much googling I have found cakephp is an emerging MVC framework in php.
but still there is lack of information that gives me answer for my question "Is cakephp suitable for enterprise application?
Or is there any other php MVC framework which is better than cakephp I can look for?

Comment: try Yii framework
[Yii Framework](http://yiiframework.com)

Comment: this question is not suitable for SO.

Comment: Please define what an "enterprise application" is. An application used in an enterprise? There are many many horrible one-off scripts used all over enterprises, Cake can hardly be worse...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is - if it is used correctly. But as with any other framework, if you got some people who does not have the most less knowledge about programming they'll abuse the framework and you end up with a huge pile of crap. I had to deal with such code ruins made in I.. you know...

My personal opinion and experience based on code I've seen is that other frameworks like Symfony and Code Igniter are less strict and less "convention over configuration" and invite less experienced people to scatter their usual garbage through the whole MVC model. I'm not saying they're bad but make it easy for people with bad habits.

When it comes to this nonsense of benchmarking frameworks you should think ahead and think of maintainability of the code base that you or your programmers will produce and what else a framework offers you. Just echoing something in a controller or loading a single blog page is not a real benchmark by the way. Think about this: Which effort do I have to spend in getting my high traffic page built, maintained and how much effort will I have with framework X to implement caching techniques? Whatever framework you choose it is again about the programmers using it correctly.

My workmate just had the idea to writing a micro framework that will be faster than any other just to proof this silly point of thinking that performance is all you should care about.

I also suggest you to not over-optimize to early, care more about a maintainable codebase and choose your developers wise. If you have an in-house team either have them to learn the framework properly or let them work with what they're familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

You know http://www.digg.com is made in CakePHP.

Comment: I don't know about digg but addons.mozilla.org is (was?) powered by cake. Here is their talk about it: http://tv.cakephp.org/video/CakeFoundation/2011/01/24/laura_thomson_-_building_the_addons_mozilla_org_api_with_cakephp This talk will give some insight into how a high traffic site is built with cake. Edit: Thats pretty old and was using 1.2, 2.2 would make this even more easier and a lot faster. :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know, if cakephp is suitable for enterprise applications, but Symfony is.
http://symfony.com/